# MongoDB filtering and sorting an array

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to find by a certain _id and then filter the author,subject,content and date and also do a sort({timestamp:-1}).

My data looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "message": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "609cbe47a45b594af4bc6b5a"
        },
        "author": "Dr. Jameson",
        "subject": "Lab Results Uploaded",
        "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sceleri...",
        "timestamp": {
            "$date": "2021-05-13T05:51:03.793Z"
        },
        "lastDateRead": {
            "$date": "2021-05-13T05:51:03.793Z"
        }
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "609cbe47a45b594af4bc6b5b"
        },
        "author": "Dr. Johnson",
        "subject": "Lab Results",
        "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sceleri...",
        "timestamp": {
            "$date": "2021-05-13T05:51:03.793Z"
        },
        "lastDateRead": {
            "$date": "2021-05-13T05:51:03.793Z"
        }
    }]
}
```

So I need to check if _id the top level is 1 and then go into messages and filter the rest based off a variable and pass the rest back.

Current code which finds by id correctly

```
async function findPatientById(client, id) {
    const result = await client.db("any").collection("any").findOne({ _id: id});
    if (result) {
        console.log(`Found in the collection with the id '${id}'`);
        console.log(result);
    } else {
        console.log(`None found with the id'${id}'`);
    }
}
```

So if I passed "Dr. Jameson" as a variable and id =1 it would give

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "609cbe47a45b594af4bc6b5a"
    },
    "author": "Dr. Jameson",
    "subject": "Lab Results Uploaded",
    "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sceleri...",
    "timestamp": {
        "$date": "2021-05-13T05:51:03.793Z"
    },
    "lastDateRead": {
        "$date": "2021-05-13T05:51:03.793Z"
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to do this filtering? On DB level or after fetching data from DB?

Comment: your statement *go into messages and filter the rest based off a variable and pass the rest back* is not clear, can you explain more, and add expected result if possible.

Comment: What I wanted to do was pass in a filter like a string 'Dr. Jameson' and from there return an array that is filtered to display values matching from the nested value.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan: If `messages` array has only one `"author": "Dr. Jameson"` then why do you need to sort on `timestamp`? Does it have multiple sub-docs with author as `Jameson`?

Comment: The data might not be sorted. It might have multiple sub-docs.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan *pass in a filter like a string 'Dr. Jameson'* you know  the key `author` that you are looking for right?

Comment: Not the exact author but something like a variable which checks for likeness on an onchange event. So it could be "Dr. J" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB you can't do it with `.find()`, you need to use `.aggregate()` thru which you can perform more complex reads.

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: "1" } }, //filter docs
  { $unwind: "$message" }, // unwind array
  { $match: { "message.author": "Dr. Jameson" }}, //Add more filters
  { $sort: { "message.timestamp": -1 } },
  { $group: { _id: "$_id", message: { $push: "$message" } } } // Re-group messages array
])
```

Alternative to `$unwind` you can use `$filter` stage to achieve same results. Don't forget to use proper indexes

**Ref :** [MongoDB-Aggregation-Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BSpkN51Gyn2)

Comment: Is there a  $match based off not a complete match but a partial match.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan: what do you mean by partial match ? You can use regex`/Jam/`, or check for `$regex` stage!

Comment: Is there a way to OR the matches?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan: not getting your question completely! But check this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/

Regex like : `"message.author": /Jam/`